# Sony a7III starts shooting JPEG even after I choose RAW

Tags: sony-alpha

Despite the fact that I set to RAW, at some point the camera begins to shoot JPEGs only. My guess is that this is related to the space available on the SD card. If so, is there any way to turn this off and continue shooting RAW until the card is full?

Comment: Did you change the mode you shoot (A, M, S, P)?

Comment: I alternate between A and M.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a custom button set to "File Format" and are hitting accidentally? There isn't a function to revert to JPG when running out of space.

Comment: Is card almost full perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I found 3 more people encountering this. At first I thought the same as you: the space does no longer suffise for another raw, so the camera fills the rest with jpgs.

However, this also happened to a wedding photographer in-midst a burst shooting. So there is no way, the person could accidentally switch any relevant setting while holding down the shutter button.

**I believe you encountered a firmware bug.**

You can find out your version number in the settings / setup-tag / version. With that information please go to the Sony website and check if that is the most current version.